# How to write Integration test for a microservice if it calling another microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I am writing an Integration Test(after here refer as IT)for my feature. In my requirement i need to call another service to update the data.these services cant be run locally so cant run Postman. SO only i am allow to use IT.

EX.
I have 2 services serviceA and serviceB , in microservice serviceA , I am writing code my feature logic and to update some data in DB(another schema for serviceB) i need to call serviceB.
I have written the code in A and now i am making a call

```
public void addUToG(UGT ugt, String accessToken)  {
    try {
        String url = ServiceB_Baseurl + "/" + id + "/works";
        HttpResponse response = httpUtil.putRequest(url, accessToken,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString(),
                mapper.writeValueAsString(ugt));
        if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            logger.warn("Failed ");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Exception ", e);
    }
}
```

Here I making a call to other service, but i need to test this with IT and I cant run postman as these services cant be run locally.
So i have no idea what can i do to test it ?Any suggestions would be great help.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

> I cant run postman as these services cant be run locally

That basically means you don't have an option to call the other service since it is not running.

But at the same time, you want to test your logic in the current service then you definitely need to **mock** this API call.

How exactly to mock it depends on your implementation, but I recommend overviewing the [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) framework first.

Based on the code snippet provided you may mock the instance of the `httpUtil`.
In this case, `httpUtil.putRequest(...)` will not be calling the real API of serviceB but instead using the response you provide for testing.

Comment: I think I have a problem regarding the same topic. I still cannot fix it. I hope you can help me .Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-url-of-another-mo

Answer (score 1):

you can use a mock http server like wiremock and stub responses to include in your integration test if you aren't doing an actual e2e test.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test your microservice under test ([SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)) you will use a [test double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) to simulate the dependent components. You can use one of the [API mocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools) tools to mock/simulate microservice B as on the diagram below.

For example, you can use one of the tools listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools):

- OpenSource [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) or [Mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/) for HTTP REST services
- Commercial Traffic Parrot for [gRPC](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/mocking-and-simulating-grpc.html) and [other protocols](https://trafficparrot.com/features.html)

For more details and options when testing microservices I recommend reviewing "[Testing Microservices: an Overview of 12 Useful Techniques](https://www.infoq.com/articles/twelve-testing-techniques-microservices-intro/)".

[image]

Comment: I have a similar issue but I cannot solve it. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-another-service-m